# how to connect a apache server instance and mysql server instance in gcp?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, mysql, google-cloud-platform

(In google cloud platform)I have created a linux/apache server in one instance and one sql server instance in another. Now i need to deploy a code in apache server and my data should be stored/retrieved in MySql server instance. please explain me how can i do it